# Who uses/used the Rambams hagadah for the Seder?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, rambam

Who uses/used the Rambam's Hagadah for the Seder (besides Teimanim)?

Answer (score 1):

Modern Rambamist's also use it.  These are non-Yeminite communities who have decided, usually as individuals, to follow Mishneh Torah almost exclusively, instead of later authorities like the Shulchan Aruch.

I know of one such community in Beit Shemesh here in Israel, [Ohel Moshe](http://www.torathmoshe.com/).

Answer (score -1):

I intend to, if that's of any value. I also hope to put together a Heb/Eng version for next year.